# Find all lines that contain specific strings in notepad++

Tags: string, find, notepad++

I have text file and I would like to search for lines that has specific partial strings and shows only the lines that has those strings

## Example:

> Please help me in this issue
>   Thanks a lot for great help
>   I receive help in this forum in great way. Please have a look
>   You are great people
>   Help me please
>   in this line help is only exists

These lines have to be searched by any string, in this case both `pleas` and "help". No case sensitivity is required.

### The expected lines that would be displayed :

> Please help me in this issue
>   I receive help in this forum in great way. Please have a look
>   Help me please

I have used this pattern and it works well for me

```
(?-s)(?=.*plea)(?=.*help).*
```

Comment: After some search I found this way

(plea[^\r\n]+hel|hel[^\r\n]+plea)

Is there more suitable solutions?

Answer (score 7):

- Go to Search -> Find (Ctrl+F).
- In the "Find what" text box enter your search terms separated by a pipe, for example "apple|juice".
- If your search terms contain special characters (dot, asterisk, parenthesis, braces etc) be sure to escape them with a "\". For example if you want to search for all lines that contain "(apple)" or "{juice}" your search string would look like "(apple)|{juice}".
- After you've written your search string go to "Search Mode" choose "Regular Expression".
- Finally, press the "Find all in Current Document" button.

Answer (score 0):

In `notepad++` use `please|help` in the search box and set it to regex. The `|` searches for either please or help since it's the or operator. Make sure you check the newline and ignore case checkbox.

Look at this site to get more familiar with regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

```js
var matches = document.querySelector("#example")
myRe = /please|help/ig;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(matches.textContent)) !== null) {
  var len = myArray[0].length;
  var startIndex = myArray.index;
  setSelectionRange(matches, startIndex, startIndex+len);
  replaceSelectionWithHtml('<span class="highlight">'+myArray[0]+'</span>');
}

//courtesy to Tim Down
function setSelectionRange(el, start, end) {
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(el);
        var foundStart = false;
        var charCount = 0, endCharCount;

        for (var i = 0, textNode; textNode = textNodes[i++]; ) {
            endCharCount = charCount + textNode.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charCount
                    && (start < endCharCount ||
                    (start == endCharCount && i <= textNodes.length))) {
                range.setStart(textNode, start - charCount);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end <= endCharCount) {
                range.setEnd(textNode, end - charCount);
                break;
            }
            charCount = endCharCount;
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

function replaceSelectionWithHtml(html) {
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), child;
        while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
            frag.appendChild(child);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
}

function getTextNodesIn(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    } else {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
            textNodes.push.apply(textNodes, getTextNodesIn(children[i]));
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}
```

```css
.highlight{
   background-color: midnightblue;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">Please help me in this issue Thanks a lot for great help I receive help in this forum in great way. Please have a look You are great people Help me please in this line help is only exists these are some lines as an example these lines have to be searched by any string no case sensitive is required in search process
</div>
```

Look at this example in JS. It works the same: